# cordova - android app crashes when receive one push notification

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, visual-studio-cordova

I made an android app with Cordova 3.0 & Visual Studio 2013; in this app I has used this [Push Notification](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) pluglin with the Google Cloud Messaging Service.

The register App works fine, because I get te RegID from GCM, and the register in my Web Server works fine too, however, I have an issue when I send any notification to devices: the App crashes when receive the Push, and does not show nothing.

I don't have log because the App is on Cordova and Visual Studio can't debug this application type.

Please help me to resolve this.

Thank you in advance. Regards from Mexico.

Comment: post the error console crash report...

Comment: what error message you got?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can debug phonegap apps with visual studio 2013 and 2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, indeed, after of much research, I finally could Debug my App in VS (I had a Issue when start the adb.exe). In the Log, I could look that my code had a bug when create the Receiver, this is the bug: `Unable to instantiate receiver com.myapp.GcmBroadcastReceiver`

I looked about this and find that was possible have a bug in my AndroidManifest.xml; then i followed the instructions exactly like the Cordova's documentation and then... This Works!

This is the Android Manifest permissions and more ([Here is the Docs](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.phonegap.plugins.pushplugin)):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="$PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="$PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<activity android:name="com.plugin.gcm.PushHandlerActivity"/>
<receiver android:name="com.plugin.gcm.CordovaGCMBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="$PACKAGE_NAME" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name="com.plugin.gcm.GCMIntentService" />
```

Thank you all